# ASP.NET Core Web API - CS0161 'AdminMandateRepository.GetUnapprovedMandateAsync(PagingFilter)': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I have this code:

```
    public async Task<IQueryable<Mandate>> GetUnapprovedMandateAsync(PagingFilter filter)
    {
        var userName = _currentUserService.UserName;
        var getUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
        var loggedUserRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(getUser);
        var loggedUserRoleName = loggedUserRole[0].ToString();

        if (loggedUserRoleName == "Operations")
        {
            var mandates = _dbContext.Mandates
                        .Where(m => (bool)m.MandateApproval.IsFirstLevelApproved == false)
                        .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery) || x.Merchant.MerchantName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                    || x.Merchant.AccountNumber.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                    || x.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                    || x.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()))
                        .Include(x => x.Merchant)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
            return mandates;
        }
        if (loggedUserRoleName == "Accountant")
        {
            var mandates = _dbContext.Mandates
                        .Where(m => (bool)m.MandateApproval.IsSecondLevelApproved == false)
                        .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery) || x.Merchant.MerchantName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                    || x.Merchant.AccountNumber.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                    || x.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                    || x.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()))
                        .Include(x => x.Merchant)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
            return mandates;
        }
    }
```

I got this error:

> CS0161    'AdminMandateRepository.GetUnapprovedMandateAsync(PagingFilter)': not all code paths return a value

But I return mandates

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Missing `return` after the final `if`. You can think this way, what if `loggedUserRoleName` is neither "Operations" nor "Accountant", what should be returned?

Comment: @YongShun - It can only be those two. What do I do? Kindly assist. Even if it's none

Comment: Maybe `return null;`?